# How to use CSS to create two column page layout?

Tags: css, html, web

I would like to create a two column web page as in [that example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/stBH4.png). Each column contains some description for the photo next to it - do you know how to use css to achieve that?

Comment: [CSS Floats](http://alistapart.com/article/css-floats-101). Happy learning.

Answer (score 2):

```css
.col-half {
  width: 40%;
  float: left;
  padding:15px;
}

.col-half div {
  background-color:orange;
  color:white;
  margin:5px;
  border:1px solid black;
  background-image:url('http://img1.wikia.nocookie.net/__cb20100915194254/starwars/images/7/7f/Jabba_SWSB.png');
  background-size:cover;
  min-height:150px;
}
```

```html
<div class='col-half'>
  <div>asdf</div>
  <div>zyzzz</div>
  <div>asdf</div>
  <div>12345</div>
</div>
<div class='col-half'>
  <div>asdf</div>
  <div>zyzzz</div>
  <div>asdf</div>
  <div>12345</div>
</div>
```

Note the width is 40%, this is to make room for margin/padding. You can adjust this as you see fit.

Answer (score 0):

You could use {float: left;} or {display: inline-element;} with a {width: 49%} or so.

Here is a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/fkcpk640/).

```
.half-column {
width: 49%; 
display: inline-block; 
vertical-align: top; 
margin-bottom:10px; 
margin-right:0.5%;}
```

If you decide to use floats like other people have mentioned, remember to add a {clear: both;} on an empty div or on your next element. For example:

1) `<div style="clear: both;"></div>` right after your floated elements. Or

2) Add :after selector to the :last-child,

```
.half-column:last-child:after {content:'.'; clear: both; visibility: hidden;}
```

Comment: I think people usually use an :after selector to place a clear:both rule directly after the floated element

Comment: That is another way to do it. Thank you for sharing. I have edited my answer to add your suggestion.

Comment: Is there a reason you put '.' instead of just '' in the content rule? I've seen this, but never knew why..

Comment: I don't know the answer to that. I added it to the answer as a precaution to make sure it works, in theory. Floats aren't my thing, but I'll keep it mind to test in the near future.

Answer (score 0):

```
#left{
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding:15px;
  text-align:left;
}

#right{
  float: right;
  width:50%;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding:15px;
  text-align:left;
}
```

You can also use frameworks like [bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/) for column layout.  Just include the files

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
```

and then you can set up columns based on their [grid system](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid) like so..

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-6">.col-md-6</div>
  <div class="col-md-6">.col-md-6</div>
</div>
```

Comment: why use `position: relative;`?

Comment: @dowomenfart oops meant to take that out... thanks!